# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION while building android app

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

I have checked multiple times for duplicate dependencies but cannot find anything. Here are the screenshots.

Here is my build.gradle file
[image: gradle.build file]

Here is my file structure.
[image: file structure]

Here is the error
[image: Error]

Please help. It was running perfect since this morning.

Answer (score 1):

try this and let me know

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    // other configurations

}
```

Comment: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package 'samarth.learning.http'

Comment: UNEXPECTED TOP LEVEL EXCEPTION with Error Code 2

Comment: I copied the project folder in a new location (on my desktop) and invalidated the cache and restarted the studio. It worked. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

When I have same issue, I replaced **compile** with **provided**.

And recommendation - use concrete library that need your app like described here - http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/12/google-play-services-and-dex-method.html